# Giving size to Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Is it possible to specify size of a frame in a tkinter window.

What i am trying to do is
I have two Frames inside a MAIN frame and I need them to take the available space in 7:3 Ratio.

I failed to find solution to my problem.

My expected result is this.[image]

1. Which layout manager will provide me this feature
2. Will it restrict any other feature
3. Will it resize itself if window is resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the `place` with `relx`, `rely`, `relheight` and `relwidth`.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg='green')
frame1.place(relx=0.0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.7)

#tk.Label(frame1, text='70%', bg='red').pack(expand=1, fill='both')

frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='blue')
frame2.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

#tk.Label(frame2, text='30%', bg='yellow').pack(expand=1, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly as expected, 
But for knowledge is it possible to do with any other manager.

Comment: @EzyGrip You probably can, but I don't think you will get this control when using other layout managers.